# Keycloak duplicate registration page

Tags: java, keycloak

I have a case where I need to separate the users by type in Keycloak.Basiacally the entire application is separated by two user types. For the purposes of the example let's say a seller and a buyer. Both of them SHOULD have their own registration page since the props for the two are different. Is there a way to duplicate the registration page with configuration or is there a workaround without extending or coding on the Keycloak codebase? Using the keycloak api to bypass the registration page is not recommended.

So far I have researched multitenancy options as described in the official documentation but it is clearly stated that the two realms cannot cross access their resources and in my case a buyer needs to see what a seller sells....

Comment: How is this question related to programming? Do you want to programmatically duplicate the registration page? If so: do you want to use keycloak's built-in registration page, or do you want to write it "outside" of keycloak?

Comment: @Turing85 I think you are right. Maybe its not related to programming and more related to architectural desicions, so where should this question be moved? The answer related to the programming is- programatically duplicate the registration page and avoid bypassing the api.

Comment: If it is about architecture, you may want to take a look at [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). From what I read, however (without knowing the exact use case), it sound like you may want to have two realms, which keycloak supports.

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you very much. In the case the seller needs to see what the buyer is selling. From what I can see in the documentation, realms cannot cross access their resources.